# strange statement in proof of entropy of a sum

Tags: entropy

In the Solutions to Problems book for Cover & Thomas's information theory book, one part of the question 14 on the entropy of a sum says,
with $Z=X+Y$,

"We have 
$$
 H(Z) \le H(X,Y) \le H(X) + H(Y)
$$
...
with equality iff (X,Y) is a function of $Z$ and $X,Y$ are independent".

My question is about the "(X,Y) is a function of $Z$" statement. What does it mean?

Does this mean that the sum $Z=X+Y$ does not have any further quantization,
so that (for example) $Y=Z-X$ is always true?

I take it that this statement is related to the inequality $H(Z) \le H(X+Y)$
and is *not* related to $H(X+Y) \le H(X) + H(Y)$. If so,
$$
  H(X+Y) = H(X)+H(Y)
$$ iff $X,Y$ are independent, with no further qualifications.
Is that correct?

EDIT:

Edit: There was a huge typo in the question, totally broken (thank you Dougal). Corrected now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've slightly misquoted the solution. What they actually say is:

> We have
>   $$ H(Z) \le H(X, Y) \le H(X) + H(Y)$$
>   [...] We have equality iff $(X, Y)$ is a function of $Z$ and $H(Y) = H(Y \mid X)$, i.e., $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

Note that the middle term is $H(X, Y)$, not $H(X + Y)$ (which is just exactly $H(Z)$ by definition).

The second inequality comes from
$$H(X, Y) = H(X) + H(Y \mid X)$$
and then using $H(Y \mid X) \le H(Y)$.
Thus the equality is tight iff $H(Y \mid X) = H(Y)$, which occurs iff $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

The first, $H(Z) \le H(X, Y)$, is the data processing inequality, since $Z = X + Y$ is a function of $(X, Y)$. Consider that via [the chain rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_entropy#Chain_rule),
$$
H(X, Y, Z) - H(Z) = H(X, Y \mid Z)
.$$
Of course, $H(X, Y, Z) = H(X, Y)$, since $Z = X + Y$ is determined exactly by $(X, Y)$. Thus $$H(X, Y) = H(Z) \quad\text{ iff }\quad H(X, Y \mid Z) = 0.$$ This is what the solutions mean: if you exactly know $(X, Y)$ given a particular $Z$, then "$(X, Y)$ is a function of $Z$": there is some $f$ such that deterministic $f(Z) = (X, Y)$.

Comment: This is nearly an answer, thank you. One question though, about what it means to know $(X,Y)$ given $Z$.
In the case of adding two general integers, you cannot know this. Possibly I do not understand the meaning of adding RVs correctly.  Does this mean that $X, Y$ have special restricted
values, such as $X \in \{ 0,1 \}$, $Y \in \{4,6\}$, so if $Z=X+Y= 5$, we know that $X=1$ and $Y=4$. 
Is this the correct meaning?

Comment: Yes, it would be have to be some situation like that.