# Alternate expression for P(X+Y|X)?

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability

I am trying to solve this problem (no one has yet answered, though the comment by Xi'an says it is simple!)

[entropy: is H(X+Y) = H(X) + H(X+Y)|X) true?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/338902/entropy-is-hxy-hx-hxyx-true)

In writing out the entropy expression, one of the probabilities is $P(X+Y|X)$.
Does this expand or simplify to any other expression that could be used?

(I do not think so..., but tell me your answer)

It is not for a class. Reading a textbook (Cover Information theory), I am just stuck on this small pirnt.

Comment: Try writing it out more explicitly... $P(X+Y = y|X=x)$. Do you see the simplification now? Hint: You can write this in terms of $P(Y = ?).

Comment: I will work on this and come back.

Comment: So the answer by Xi'an to the other post about entropy (linked above) gives the answer to this question inside the answer to that question. However, though I understand the overall idea, there are two formal details that are new to me. Since they are the same for this question I would like to ask about these small details.
I will show the proof, and my questions, but tomrrow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by knrumsey in the comment to the question you are conditioning on $X$ being a known quantity, effectively making $X$ a constant $X=x$.

Understanding the notation matters a lot here. The quantity $X$ is a random variable and $x$ is the value that $X$ equals in this scenario. The comment differs slightly in statement from the linked post, in the linked post the equation is written $\Pr(X+Y=x+y|X=x).$ Now we know that this is equivalently, $\Pr(X+Y=x+y|X=x)=\Pr(x+Y=y+x|X=x)$ and this second expression for the event ${x+Y=y+x|X=x}$ can subtract the $x$ from each side, *because this is a constant in this event*. Writing the resulting event is then $\Pr(x+Y=y+x|X=x)=\Pr(Y=y| X=x)$ which is the claim in the underbrace in Xi'an's post.

Comment: Looks like you did not finish editing (maybe clean up?), but I _think_ I understand.

Restatement: since X=x is a constant, you can change X to x on the left side of the conditional, then it is just a constant offset that "shifts" the value of Y, and does not affect the probability distribution of Y.

Is that right?

Comment: @isolatedstudent yes, the rest shouldn't of updated in the post, I'll remove the dangling language. If this clarifies please consider marking as correct.

Comment: i have learned something valuable.